# Conversion from unix timestamp to local time

Tags: php

I need to convert the unix timestamp stored from the database to the local timezones (US, Singapore , etc )in the Y-m-d H:i:s format.

**$selectedTime** is the Unix Timestamp returned from DB.

**$timezone_name** is the timezone dynamically returned from jquery.

```
function draw_date_time_form($selectedTime = '',$timezone_name){

   $date = new DateTime(null);

    if( is_numeric($selectedTime) && (int)$selectedTime == $selectedTime ){
         $date->setTimestamp($selectedTime);
         $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($timezone_name));

                 $formattedtime= $date->format(DateTime::RFC850);
        }

        }
```

I am getting the localtime  **$formattedtime** in the server default timezone set.
Could anyone help me with a better solution?

Answer (score 4):

Basic example of your request:

```
$timestamp = 1371278212;
$timezone = "UTC";
$dt = new DateTime();
$dt->setTimestamp($timestamp);
$dt->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($timezone));
$datetime = $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ::

```
function draw_date_time_form($selectedTime = '',$timezone_name){

   $date = new DateTime();

    if( is_numeric($selectedTime) && (int)$selectedTime == $selectedTime ){
         $date->setTimestamp($selectedTime);
         $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($timezone_name));

                 $formattedtime= $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        }

}
```